# MS Access VBA SQL SELECT * INTO tempTbl WHERE Stuff="" AND OtherStuff BETWEEN Date Range

Tags: sql, date-range, ms-access-2016

I have a form with one text box, two combo boxes (dropdowns), and two text boxes with input masks for `mm/dd/yyyy  99/99/0000;0;_`

I am attempting to use all of these fields as filters for a subform. 
I have the controls set to fire after update and run a sub that builds a `SELECT * INTO` sql string for a temp Table that is then `sourceobject'ed` back to the `subform`.

In code I have for each control I have code building a snippet of the Where statement for the final `sql`. the snippet grows as needed, is labeled "Filter"

Some other non-Finished Code....

```
If Not IsNull(txtDateFrom) Then
If i > 1 Then Filter = Filter & " AND " & "([Date_LastSaved] >= " & Me.txtDateFrom & ")" & " And " & "([Date_LastSaved] <= " & Me.txtDateTo & ")"
End If


Dim sql As String
sql = "SELECT * INTO tmpTable FROM tblReview"
If Not IsNull(Filter) Then
    sql = sql & " WHERE " & Filter
End If
```

My issue and question is that I am testing this one specific situation where there will be `Filter = Filter & " AND " & "DATE_STUFF"`

where the final sql looks like...

`SELECT * INTO tmpTable FROM tblReview WHERE ReviewStatus = 'Quoted' AND ([Date_LastSaved] >= 09/12/2018) And ([Date_LastSaved] <= 10/16/2018)`

which should have some result with the test data. Yet, the tmpTable is empty.

This is only happening when I apply a date range criteria.

I tried `BETWEEN` but could not nail down the syntax.

Any insight is greatly appreciated, Thanks!

UPDATE:
Answer:

```
If i > 1 Then Filter = Filter & " AND " & "([Date_LastSaved] >= #" & Me.txtDateFrom & "#)" & " And " & "([Date_LastSaved] <= #" & Me.txtDateTo & "#)"
```

Comment: What is `i`? And did you try the sql query direct on the db?

Comment: i is some counter of mine working on how to loop through each cntrl and keep out the extra "AND" in the final sql, as I couldn't come up with a good loop to do it. -Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use dates then they must be quoted. If you just say 10/16/2018 then you are dividing the integer 10 by 16 by 2018 which will yield an integer zero. It will then convert the dates to an integer to do the compare, which will yield a much bigger number, and thus you get no rows.

Any date testing should always be done using date types rather than strings. I think in msaccess you can surround it in #, but not sure. Just research this.

Comment: Aha! There it is! the # sign...forgot all about including it into the string layout. Thank you for the answer!